# Error publishing database along with web-app to Microsoft Azure in VS15

Tags: database, azure, web-applications

I am able to successfully publish my web-app without the database and it works perfect. But, since it is dynamic, I need to attach database to it but i am not able to do so. 
It's raising an error when previewing database.
[image]

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: SQLServer2014- @AlexBelotserkovskiy